# Google TV emulator without chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-tv

Is it normal not to have the Google Chrome browser on a google TV emulator in a Linux machine with KVM enabled?
When launching an `Intent` from my application that hits a web page,
I get the error message `"No activity found to handle intent {act=android.intent.action.VIEW, dat=http://...}"` and I have tried several web addresses.
The code from My Activity is this and it works fine in other android platforms:

```
Intent myIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                           Uri.parse( "http://www.test.com");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Am I missing some step to install the Google Chrome browser? On the other hand I can not find the Google Market application neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly it is normal not to have the Chrome browser installed with the emulator. This does make it a bit of a pain to do things like you are trying currently. I'm not sure if there are plans for adding Chrome to the emulator in the future, but in the meantime, it is possible to install Browser.apk (the Android browser) to the emulator (via `adb install Browser.apk`, which you can either build from AOSP or possibly pull from a device or standard Android emulator via `adb pull /system/app/Browser.apk` - I think this is the default Browser location on devices).

Once Browser.apk is installed you should be able to test these things as you would expect.

So the steps are:

1. Start an emulator with Android 3.1 running
2. `adb -s device_id pull /system/app/Browser.apk`
3. `adb -s device_id install Browser.apk`

Comment: Perfect. It worked like a charm.
I found the browser in another virtual device using the Android 3.1 Target:
1- Started the Android 3.1 device
2- Extracted the Browser.apk (adb pull /system/app/Browser.apk)
3- Shutted down the Android 3.1 device
4- Started the Google TV device
5- Installed the Browser.apk (adb install /system/app/Browser.apk)
6- Started to play

Txs

Comment: Thanks for these instructions. Minor tweak is that step 5 should be: 'adb install Browser.apk'

Comment: Hi, where should I type in these commands?  From the Linux terminal?  Do I need to navigate to a certain folder?

Comment: Keep mind, while this is a great tip that will allow the emulator to handle a VIEW intent to an HTTP URI (as the OP requested) the Browser app is NOT the same as the Chrome that comes on GTV. If you're doing other web stuff you might get different results.

Comment: If someone is wonder what is device_id, can find from the command "adb devices" , it will show yuour the deviuce_id of the connected device.

Answer (score 1):

In the Android smart TV emulator, I've tried the simplest method to download the Chrome browser.
Drag and drop the APK onto the emulator after downloading it from the provided link. After you will allow from to **Settings > Device Preferences > Security & Restrictions > Unknown sources**

[Chrome APK Download URL](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-87-0-4280-66-release/google-chrome-fast-secure-87-0-4280-66-9-android-apk-download/)

Second

[Alternate you can follow the article link](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-sideload-apps-android-tv/)