# How to link to a website in Google TV?

Tags: android, hyperlink, google-tv

In my preference activity I have one preference that links to a website  (eg.  stackoverflow.com). The code works fine in everything EXCEPT a Google TV emulator.  On the Google TV emulator clicking the preference creates a Force Close.

```
Log Cat says "02-21 12:13:59.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1993): 
  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
  Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.stackoverflow.com }
```

Here is my code that I'm using...

```
getPreferenceManager().findPreference("pref_visit_web").setOnPrndeferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)     {

        Intent v = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        v.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
    startActivity(v);


        return false;
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. Chrome is not installed on the Google TV Emulator (and there is therefore no browser available to handle that intent) [at least as of now].

It should work on a real device though.

Comment: Thankyou, here is a related question...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209387/google-tv-emulator-without-chrome-browser