# Browser For Google Tv Emulator

Tags: google-tv

I have installed Linux OS with KVM and Android SDK. After that, I installed Google TV Add-on to it.

Next, I created AVD Google TV Addon (Google, Inc.) - API Level 12 with a screen resolution of 720p.

After running the emulator, the emulator works fine, but the emulator does not contain any browser. How to install the browser(google chrome)? I would like to run my web application in a Google TV emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Browser is not supported in emulator. Please refer to this post for a workaround:
[Google TV emulator without chrome browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209387/google-tv-emulator-without-chrome-browser)

Also, please file a feature request :

http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/